# How can I load the weights of some layer of a trained network in a new network in returnn?

Tags: python, tensorflow, returnn

I have the trained weights of the following network in a folder path/to/modelFile:

```
network={
"conv_1" : {"class": "conv", "filter_size": (400,), "activation":"abs" , "padding": "valid", "strides": 10, "n_out": 64 },
"pad_conv_1_time_dim" : {"class": "pad", "axes": "time", "padding": 20, "from": ["conv_1"]},
"conv_2" : {"class": "conv", "input_add_feature_dim": True, "filter_size": (40, 64), "activation":"abs", "padding": "valid","strides": 16, "n_out": 128, "from": ["pad_conv_1_time_dim"]},
"flatten_conv": {"class": "merge_dims", "axes": "except_time","n_out": 128,  "from": ["conv_2"]},
"window_1": {"class": "window", "window_size": 17, "from": ["flatten_conv"]},
"flatten_window": {"class": "merge_dims", "axes":"except_time","from": ["window_1"]},
"lin_1" :   { "class" : "linear", "activation": None, "n_out": 512,"from" : ["flatten_window"] },
"ff_2" :   { "class" : "linear", "activation": "relu", "n_out": 2000, "from" : ["lin_1"] },
"output" :   { "class" : "softmax", "loss" : "ce", "from" : ["ff_2"] }
}
```

and I want to load the trained weights of the layers "conv_1" and "conv_2" into the following network:

```
network={
"conv_1" : {"class": "conv", "filter_size": (400,), "activation": "abs" , "padding": "valid", "strides": 10, "n_out": 64 },
"pad_conv_1_time_dim" : {"class": "pad", "axes": "time", "padding": 20, "from": ["conv_1"]},
"conv_2" : {"class": "conv", "input_add_feature_dim": True, "filter_size": (40, 64), "activation":"abs", "padding": "valid", "strides": 16, "n_out": 128, "from": ["pad_conv_1_time_dim"]},
"flatten_conv": {"class": "merge_dims", "axes": "except_time", "n_out": 128,  "from": ["conv_2"]},
"lstm1_fw" : { "class": "rec", "unit": "lstmp", "n_out" : rnnLayerNodes, "direction": 1, "from" : ['flatten_conv'] },
"lstm1_bw" : { "class": "rec", "unit": "lstmp", "n_out" : rnnLayerNodes, "direction": -1, "from" : ['flatten_conv'] },
"lin_1" :   { "class" : "linear", "activation": None, "n_out": 512, "from" : ["lstm1_fw", "lstm1_bw"] },
"ff_2" :   { "class" : "linear", "activation": "relu", "n_out": 2000, "from" : ["lin_1"] },
"ff_3" :   { "class" : "linear", "activation": "relu", "n_out": 2000,"from" : ["ff_2"] },
"ff_4" :   { "class" : "linear", "activation": "relu", "n_out": 2000,"from" : ["ff_3"] },
"output" :   { "class" : "softmax", "loss" : "ce", "from" : ["ff_4"] }
}
```

How is that possible in returnn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `SubnetworkLayer` is one option. That would look like:

```
trained_network_model_file = 'path/to/model_file'

trained_network = {
"conv_1" : {"class": "conv", "filter_size": (400,), "activation": "abs" , "padding": "valid", "strides": 10, "n_out": 64 },
"pad_conv_1_time_dim" : {"class": "pad", "axes": "time", "padding": 20, "from": ["conv_1"]},
"conv_2" : {"class": "conv", "input_add_feature_dim": True, "filter_size": (40, 64), "activation":"abs", "padding": "valid", "strides": 16, "n_out": 128, "from": ["pad_conv_1_time_dim"]},
"flatten_conv": {"class": "merge_dims", "axes": "except_time","n_out": 128,  "from": ["conv_2"]}
}

network = {
"conv_layers" : { "class" : "subnetwork", "subnetwork": trained_network, "load_on_init": trained_network_model_file, "n_out": 128},
"lstm1_fw" : { "class": "rec", "unit": "lstmp", "n_out" : rnnLayerNodes, "direction": 1, "from" : ['conv_layers'] },
"lstm1_bw" : { "class": "rec", "unit": "lstmp", "n_out" : rnnLayerNodes, "direction": -1, "from" : ['conv_layers'] },
"lin_1" :   { "class" : "linear", "activation": None, "n_out": 512, "from" : ["lstm1_fw", "lstm1_bw"] },
"ff_2" :   { "class" : "linear", "activation": "relu", "n_out": 2000, "from" : ["lin_1"] },
"ff_3" :   { "class" : "linear", "activation": "relu", "n_out": 2000, "from" : ["ff_2"] },
"ff_4" :   { "class" : "linear", "activation": "relu", "n_out": 2000, "from" : ["ff_3"] },
"output" :   { "class" : "softmax", "loss" : "ce", "from" : ["ff_4"] }
}
```

I think this would be my preferred option in your case.

Otherwise, there is the `custom_param_importer` option for every layer, and you might get it to work with that.

Then, for many layers, you can define the initializer for the params, e.g. for `ConvLayer`, you can use `forward_weights_init`. There functions like `load_txt_file_initializer` could be used, or maybe a similar function should be added to load directly from a TF checkpoint file.

Comment: If there is an "output layer" missing error in the subnetwork, one can just change the name "flatten_conv" to "output" and it should work

Comment: If weigths of the subnetwork should not be trained, the parameter  {....,"trainable":False,...} has to be added to all layers containing trainable parameters in trained_network and to the subnetwork layer "conv_layers" as well